# Скачивание файлов с URL указывая запросы GET и POST

Tags: php

Я скачиваю файл при помощи PHP:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://site.ru/index.php?request=A;'
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($url).'"');
copy($url, 'gosloto.html');
?>
```

Как видите, для скачивания я указал запрос `$_GET['request'] = 'A'` (в первой строчке `index.php?request=A;`).

А как можно указать запрос `$_POST`?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть пару методов для этого

№1

```
$url = 'http://site.ru/index.php';
$myvars = 'request=A';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

результат будет в `$response`

[источник №1](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php) [источник №2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3080222/4953620)

---

№2

```
$url = 'http://site.ru/index.php';
$data = array('request' => 'A', 'request2' => 'B');
$options = array(
        'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

[источник №1](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) [источник №2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23385319/4953620)

---

№3

```
<?php
$fields = array(
    'request' => 'А',
    'pass' => 'se_ret'
);
$files = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'uimg',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'file' => './profile.jpg',
    )
);

$response = http_post_fields("http://site.ru/index.php", $fields, $files);
?>
```

Этот пример также отправляет файл ([источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-post-fields.php))